# Replacing the literal string in this code

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to understand the following code:

```
private readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
  ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
  {
    ClientId =  "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "abcde"
  },
  Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive }
});
```

I want to replace the string literals for the ClientId and ClientSecret with values coming from a variable declared outside of this code but am not sure how. It's the first time I've seen the a class declared with two of its interal values separated by a comma. Is this some kind of anonymous function?

Comment: It's just a way of writing initialization. Feel free to replace the strings with variables.

Comment: I tried replacing it with variables but I get the red wiggly underline indicating an error. I defined the variable at the top of my class and even initialized it. Something isn't right.

Comment: Try to declare and initialize the variables just above the code you posted and see if that helps. I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameterless constructor. If you already have access to the variables just do this:

```
ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
  {
    ClientId =  varClientId,
    ClientSecret = varClientSecret
  },
```

What this is really doing is calling the default constructor, the one with no parameters, and then the syntax allows you to set `Properties`. In this case `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`.

If you don't have access to those variables, you'll need to get them in your scope.

Comment: Where do I define varClientId? I tried defining it outside of the code  but it shows a syntax error. I tried defining the variable as a member field but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndroidDev, I'm not able to really answer that for you, but you need to get them into the same scope this code is in. If it's in a method, then you may need to inject them as parameters.

Comment: The error message states: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, property varClientID

Comment: @AndroidDev So make varClientID static?

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea why people write crap code like the stuff I listed above. Here is something more humane:

```
AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer codeflowInitializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer();
codeflowInitializer.ClientSecrets = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ClientSecrets>(jsonSecrets);
codeflowInitializer.Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive };
IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(codeflowInitializer);
```